How to Handle Predictions with Two High-Cardinality Categorical Variables?
Dataset Overview
I have a dataset with three columns:

ProjectCode: A categorical variable representing the project. (~6 unique values per category)
RelSubRelPair: A categorical variable representing component pairs (~326,000 unique values).
ClearanceActual: A continuous variable representing a measurement.

Key Characteristics

Each RelSubRelPair can belong to multiple ProjectCodes (up to 6 projects).
Ideally, the ClearanceActual for the same RelSubRelPair across different projects should be consistent. When it deviates significantly, it’s considered an anomaly.
Predictions need to be within categories, i.e., the model should predict the expected ClearanceActual for a given RelSubRelPair and ProjectCode.

Goal
I need to:

Build a model that predicts ClearanceActual for a new combination of RelSubRelPair and ProjectCode.
Detect anomalies by comparing the predicted value with the actual value.

Challenges

High Cardinality: RelSubRelPair has over 326,000 unique values, which makes one-hot encoding infeasible due to memory constraints.
Categorical Dependencies: Predictions are tied to both RelSubRelPair and ProjectCode, making it non-trivial to encode and generalize.

Questions

Encoding Methods:

Would label encoding suffice for high-cardinality variables, or should I consider target encoding, embeddings, or another approach?


Model Recommendations:

Would tree-based models (e.g., Random Forest, XGBoost) or neural networks with embeddings be more suitable for this type of data?
Are there specialized techniques to make predictions within categories when there are dependencies between them?



What I’ve Tried

I attempted one-hot encoding for the categorical variables, but it caused memory issues due to the high cardinality of RelSubRelPair.
I considered label encoding, but I’m unsure if it introduces bias since it assumes ordinal relationships.

